# Removing quote-qualifiers when bulk copying data via bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using bulk insert along with format files to import large text files into a db. Some of the files are csv's with values that are occassionally double quote-qualified and those quotes are making their way into the imported table.

Is there a way w/ bulk insert to tell it not to import the quotes? I've looked at the MSDN documentation for both bulk insert and OPENROWSET as well as searched the internet w/ no luck.

Comment: I've always either (a) bulk inserted into a staging table and removed the quotes first before performing the final load (this can be safer in terms of recovery anyway), or (b) having a simple C# command-line tool to pre-parse the data file and put it into the right format.

Comment: I have it loading into a staging table today and then I replace the quotes once loaded into staging. I'm actually hoping to be able to stop doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm working with `BULK INSERT`, I like to push the data I'm inserting into a temporary `#staging_table`, usually with `varchar()` columns. This gives me a chance to look over the data before insertion and check for errors in a more friendly fashion than the raw `BULK INSERT` process does.

In your case, you might consider pushing your content to a temporary staging table, then use `UPDATE` and `REPLACE()` to remove the double-quotes before inserting the modified content from the staging table.

Comment: I'm already doing this, I'm attempting to find a way to not have to do this anymore.